# How to check if system is installed with latest python version (python3.10)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I am using following `shell` command to find the latest `python` is installed

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info)'
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

But this command is returning  the default python version (3.8) that was pointing to python3, instead of  higher python version installed (3.10).

**How to check if python3.10 version is installed in a host ?**

Comment: The output of that command will change depending on what binary “python3” points to. Run `whereis python3` — also as far as shell commands go it should be enough with `python3 --version`

Comment: Do you have any requirements or constraints to narrow down what to check? A specific OS and specific installation methods perhaps? In principle, this could require checking every single file on the host.

Comment: Beside the point, but that `[:]` is unnecessary. All it does is make a copy.

Comment: Oh whoops, I thought `sys.version_info` was a tuple.

Comment: Python 3.10 isn't the latest Python version, 3.11 is.

Comment: @Lava Sorry, I'm trying to say the question is unclear. Are you asking about the latest version of Python (3.11), or are you asking about 3.10 specifically? or maybe any specific version?

Comment: i am fine with 3.10 or 3.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out all your versions installed with (works with Red Hat and Debian derivatives with default path installations of python)

```
ls /usr/bin/python* | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+' | tr -d '.' | sort -n
```

the latest with

```
ls /usr/bin/python* | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+' | tr -d '.' | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

and to check for specific version

```
test $(ls /usr/bin/python* | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+' | tr -d '.' | sort -n | tail -n 1) -eq 310 && echo "Python version 3.10 is installed in this host." || echo "A version of python different than 3.10 is installed."
```

Comment: This is brittle because it assumes all Python versions are installed under /usr/bin.

Comment: that's right only works for default path installation.

Comment: Thanks, But this gave me 3.8 is the highest. sort is not working properly

$ ls /usr/bin/python* | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+' | sort -n
2.7
3.10
3.10
3.6
3.6
3.7
3.7
3.7
3.7
3.8
3.8

Comment: That's not the default installation path on many systems.

Comment: Tested on Red Hat and Debian derivatives with default path installations of python.

Comment: @LavaSangeetham check if ordering works properly now.

Answer (score -1):

To specify the use of version 3.10 you can use

```bash
py -3.10 -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info[:])'
```

Comment: Isn't the `py` launcher a Windows only thing?

Comment: What about the "or above"? Like what if the system has Python 3.11 installed? This only works for 3.10.

Comment: Indeed, this solution is specific for version 3.10 in Windows system...

Answer (score -1):

`compgen -c | grep -i python3.10` (or `python` to see all versions).